# I publish my new branch to the remote repo then try to merged into master branch but says merged conflict

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution, merge-request

I clone a repository in my machine and created a new_branch and commit 2 changes and tried to push my new branch to the repository.

```
git push origin new_branch
```

Then I tried to merged the new branch in my remote master branch but it say merge conflict

my master branch is uptodate but still saying merge conflict

Answer (score 1):

Try first to rebase locally your new branch on top of an updated `master` (or `main`, if you have created the repository recently, since the [default branch naming convention has changed](https://github.com/github/renaming)).

```sh
cd /path/to/local/clone
git fetch
git switch new_branch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force
```

From there, a merge to GitHub `master` should have no conflict, because any conflict would have been resolved locally first.

Comment: Woahhh your a life saver! it works

Answer (score 0):

The merge conflict is occurring because you have made separate changes in the same line of a file git is not sure which one to discard. Write
`git status`
to see the conflicts and resolve them by removing the older file

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line